# Declaring delegate protocol in the same file

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have following header:

```
@protocol AttachmentsViewDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void)spaceRequestedWithSize:(CGSize)size sender:(AttachmentsView*)sender;

@end

@interface AttachmentsView : UIView

@property id<AttachmentsViewDelegate> delegate;
@property NSArray *attachments;

- (void)takePicture;
- (void)deletePictures;

@end
```

Doesn't work because inside @protocol I reference to AttachmentsView and it's not declared yet.

If I move @protocol below @interface - I have another problem, because delegate property doesn't know about @protocol.

I know I can use id, UIView for types, but to keep it "strongly typed", what can I do? I really prefer not to break it down into 2 files. Any other options/suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@class` to forward-declare `AttachmentsView` like so:

```
@class AttachmentsView;

@protocol AttachmentsViewDelegate <NSObject>

// Protocol method declarations...

@end
```

Alternatively, use `@protocol` to forward-declare the protocol:

```
@protocol AttachementsViewDelegate

@interface AttachmentsView : UIView

// Ivar, method, and property declarations...

@property id<AttachmentsViewDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

just write:

```
@class AttachmentsView;
```

on top of the file.

In case you wish to declare the class first, and then the protocol, write first:

```
@protocol AttachmentsViewDelegate;
```

on top of the file.